# Get the selected value when changing the selected value with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'd like when I selected a value in a dropdown get the value selected.

Any idea ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready( function(){

  $('#your_select').change( function(){
    var result = $(this).val();
    do_something_with(result);
  });

});
```

Assuming HTML like this:

```
<select id="your_select" name="selectname">
  <option value="foo">Foo!</option>
  <option value="bar">Bar!</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ok when you select with the mouse to select, but not when you use the arrow keys

Comment: If you're "arrowing" through the choices in a select menu, you're not actually changing the value with each move. You're identifying the option that will become the selection when you "commit" the change, usually by hitting `enter` or `spacebar`. That's when the `change` event is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').change(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/gUZhh/)

Comment: Ok when you select with the mouse to select, but not when you use the arrow keys

Comment: @Kris It should fire the event when the select loses focus if you're using the keys